# Unsure of what to put in the GROUP BY statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following code

```
Select 
                COALESCE(sh.reference, cast(sh.sales_document_num as char(20))) as CustomerOrderNumber,
                CAST('ORDL' as char(4)) as Type,
                CAST('1' as char(1)) as one,
                '' as two,
                si.sales_item_num as LineNumber,
                si.product_code as ProductCode,
                CASE
                    WHEN si.status = 2 THEN '200'
                    WHEN si.status = 3 THEN '220'
                    WHEN sr.status = 2 THEN '30'
                    ELSE '50'
                END as Status,
                si.sales_rqd_quantity as Quantity,
                si.sales_rqd_quantity - pp.quantity as InOrderQuantity,
                CAST('0' as char(1)) as seven,
                pp.quantity as DeliveredInTotal,
                CAST('0' as char(1)) as NotAvailableQuantity,
                '''' as nine,
                ph.despatch_type as DespatchType,
                ph.package_id as TrackingNumber

            FROM

                sales_header sh
                    LEFT JOIN sales_item si ON sh.sales_document_num = si.sales_document_num
                    LEFT JOIN sales_requirement sr ON sh.sales_document_num = sr.sales_document_num and si.sales_item_num = sr.sales_item_num
                    LEFT JOIN package_product pp ON si.sales_document_num = pp.sales_document_num and si.sales_item_num = pp.sales_item_num
                    LEFT JOIN package_header ph ON pp.despatch_num = ph.despatch_num

            WHERE
                SH.sales_document_num = '21199927'


            GROUP BY 
                sh.sales_document_num,
                si.sales_item_num,
                si.product_code,
                si.status,
                ph.despatch_type,
                ph.package_id
```

However I am unsure what to put in the group by clause as I am receiving this error.

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
> 00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

In the group by , do you have to put the calculation and casts etc.

Any help appreciated

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: You have no aggregation functions, so it is unclear that `group by` is even necessary.  But for your query, you can remove the `group by` and use `select distinct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it doesn't look like you are using any aggregate functions in your query and you are just trying to remove duplicate records, I would remove the group by and just do `SELECT DISTINCT...` to keep the query a bit simpler.

Comment: Yes that correct, had a lot of duplicate records